# Pose Mode extremely laggy, even with Decimate. Rigged with AccuRIG

Tags: pose-mode

This model i downloaded off of Sketchfab seems to be really, really laggy in Pose Mode. It wasn't rigged, so i used AccuRIG to fix that. When i noticed the lag, i added a decimate modifier (collapse since unsubdivide did virtually nothing) and tried again, only to find that it's still painfully slow. Here's a demonstration of my problem: [youtube link](https://youtu.be/726AdE1Yz1w)
[image: the decimated model]

Comment: It is probably too many vertices.  A live decimate modifier does not make things faster; it makes things slower.

Comment: How do i decrease the amount of vertices in the viewport without using decimate, then? Simplify only limits the amount of subdivisions, but that's about it.

Comment: You can *apply* the decimate modifier, from the dropdown menu next to the decimate modifier, if you have no shapekeys.  Or, you can use other remeshing or retopo addons/techniques (which tend to be better than decimate in terms of vertex count compared to preserved visual detail.)  Best is manual retopo, but if you're asking, you're probably not ready to embrace that yet.